# GraphQL Schema not updated with NestJS (code-first approach)

Tags: graphql, nestjs

Pretty new to GraphQL, I am facing an issue with the latest version of NestJS where I am currently trying to add a mutation to a resolver that doesn't show in the playground when the server is running.

It looks like the GraphQL schema is not updated on server launch.

The createUser mutation is showing in the GraphQL playground and working but the getUsers one (created for test purposes) is not showing.

I would appreciate any hint on how to tackle this issue.

Importation of the GraphQLMOdule in app.module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
// Libraries
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
// App modules
import { MealModule } from './meal/meal.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
// Entities
import { MealEntity } from './meal/meal.entity';
import { UserEntity } from './auth/user.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mongodb',
      url: 'mongodb://localhost/sideproject',
      synchronize: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      entities: [MealEntity, UserEntity],
    }),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      debug: true,
      playground: true
    }),
    MealModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here are the types for the user module I am experiencing difficulties with :

```
import { ObjectType, Field, ID } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@ObjectType('User')
export class UserType {
  @Field(() => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field()
  username: string;

  @Field()
  email: string;

  @Field()
  password: string;
}
```

The associated resolver :

```
import { Resolver, Mutation, Args, Query } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { UserType } from './types/user.types';
import { CreateUserInputType } from './inputs/create-user.input';
import { UserEntity } from './user.entity';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Resolver(of => UserType)
export class AuthResolver {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  @Mutation(returns => UserType)
  signUp(
    @Args('createUserInput') createUserInput: CreateUserInputType,
  ): Promise<UserEntity> {
    return this.authService.signUp(createUserInput);
  }

  @Query(returns => [UserType])
  getUsers(): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
    return this.authService.getUsers()
  }
}
```

The service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { CreateUserInputType } from './inputs/create-user.input';
import { UserRepository } from './user.repository';
import { UserEntity } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserRepository)
    private userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {}

  signUp(createUserInput: CreateUserInputType): Promise<UserEntity> {
    return this.userRepository.signUp(createUserInput);
  }

  async getUsers(): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
    return await this.userRepository.find();
  }
}
```

And finally the repository for the user module :

```
import { Repository, EntityRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from './user.entity';
import { InternalServerErrorException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateUserInputType } from './inputs/create-user.input';

import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

@EntityRepository(UserEntity)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<UserEntity> {
  async signUp(createUserInput: CreateUserInputType): Promise<UserEntity> {
    const { username, email, password } = createUserInput;

    const user = this.create();
    user.id = uuid();
    user.username = username;
    user.email = email;
    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(12));
    try {
      return await this.save(user);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: Try to delete the `schema.gql` file and re-run the server. The code you attached here is not relevant. Please attach the GraphQLModule importation piece of code, in `app.module`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my first post with the importation at the top of my post.
As you can see, I am using the { autoSchemaFile: true } option, thus no schema.gql file is created on launch.

Comment: It was a bummer but I tried to recreate a project and copied-pasted all of my files with the exact same configuration and it finally worked. 
Mystery....

Comment: Was the same problem, after removing dist folder and restart project all become OK.

Comment: It should not happen like that.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add the resolver to the providers collection for the resolvers to be available.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue and these steps solved the problem:

1. stop the server
2. remove the dist folder
3. restart the server

Answer (score 1):

In my case (using Docker), I had to clear cached volumes with:

```
docker system prune -a
```

After rebuild, schema.gql was updated.

Comment: I suffered this problem couple of times. It's so frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is : declaring the objectype only will not update the schema. including the objectype as a return type within a resolver is the key.